# Request Weight Value from Scale through COM

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, port

I've been trying to retrieve the weight value from two different scales using a COM Serial Port.

The scales are a CAS ER Plus and a UWE AM-15K.

I've already managed to create a small program to start the communication between a PC and the Scales but i'm running into a problem and I've been unable to find a solution.

I can send an ENQ command and I receive the ACK sucessfully from both scales, but when I send the DC1 command to retrieve the weight, I always get various variations from the messages

> "Hex number must be smaller than 7fffffffffffffff"

And

> "Hex Value Must be Maximum Length of 32 characters."

My code to configure the COM Port is the following:

```
Try
        comport.PortName = "COM1"
        comport.BaudRate = 9600
        comport.Parity = Parity.None
        comport.DataBits = 8
        comport.StopBits = StopBits.One
        comport.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff
        If DTRCheck.Checked Then
            comport.DtrEnable = True
        End If
        If RTSCheck.Checked Then
            comport.RtsEnable = True
        End If
        'Dim encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM860")
        Dim encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII
        comport.Encoding = encoding
        comport.Open()
        erroCOM = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        erroCOM = True
    End Try
```

My code to send the commands:

```
 If comport.IsOpen Then
        TxtValor.Clear()
        Try
            If EnqComBtn.Checked Then 'Verify if the scale is "listening"
                ListBox1.Items.Add("PC: ENQ - >")
                comport.Write(New Byte() {&H5}, 0, 1)
                Thread.Sleep(20)
                ListBox1.Items.Add("PC: DC1 - >")
                comport.Write(New Byte() {&H11}, 0, 1)
            End If
            If DC1ComBtn.Checked Then 'Request weight value
                ListBox1.Items.Add("PC: DC1 - >")
                comport.Write(New Byte() {&H11}, 0, 1)
                Thread.Sleep(20)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End If
```

After sending the commands, I have the program reading the value received through the DataReceived event from the COM Serial Port and converting the Hex values to Decimal.

EDIT:

This is the code I use to read the Bytes received and convert them from Byte to Hex. I found this code on another post here on StackOverflow and edited out the spaces part.

Private Sub comport_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles comport.DataReceived

```
    Dim RXByte As Byte
    Do
        RXCnt = 0
        Do
            RXByte = comport.ReadByte
            RXArray(RXCnt) = LookUpTable(RXByte >> 4) ' Convert each byte to two hexadecimal characters 
            RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
            RXArray(RXCnt) = LookUpTable(RXByte And 15)
            RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
        Loop Until (comport.BytesToRead = 0)
        '----- End of communication protocol handling ------------------------------------------------------------- 

        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Display)) ' Start "Display" on the UI thread 

    Loop Until (comport.BytesToRead = 0)  ' Don't return if more bytes have become available in the meantime 

End Sub
```

Has anyone found this problem before and if so, have you found a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: You did not post the code with the bug.  Remove the Thread.Sleep() calls so you cannot ignore the bug.

Comment: The thing is that as soon as I write the &H11 in the COM Port, I immediately get 15 Bytes on the COMport.BytesToRead property and after converting it from Hex to Dec, it translates to either "Hex number must be smaller than 7fffffffffffffff" or "Hex Value Must be Maximum Length of 32 characters."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem!

The thing was that I was reading the BytesToRead byte by byte, and I had to do ReadExisting.

Previous Code:

```
Dim RXByte As Byte
    'Dim RXBytes() As Byte
    Dim bytString As String = ""
    Do
        RXCnt = 0
        Do
            RXByte = comport.ReadByte
            RXArray(RXCnt) = LookUpTable(RXByte >> 4) ' Convert each byte to two hexadecimal characters 
            RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
            RXArray(RXCnt) = LookUpTable(RXByte And 15)
            RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
        Loop Until (comport.BytesToRead = 0)
        '----- End of communication protocol handling ------------------------------------------------------------- 

    Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Display)) ' Start "Display" on the UI thread 

    Loop Until (comport.BytesToRead = 0)  ' Don't return if more bytes have become available in the meantime
```

Solution:

```
RXValue = ""

    Try

        RXValue = comport.ReadExisting()
        If RXValue <> "" Then
            Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Display)) ' Start "Display" on the UI thread 
        Else

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Hope this can help others who have the same problem!